# I am getting Azure REST API 403 forbidden error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have to restart cloud service instance on specified schedule through azure function.
For this I am using Azure Resource Manager API. For that I am getting 403 error.
1.I have created APP registration in Azure AD. 
2.Given contributor role to it.
3.Used application client id, client secret, tenant at required places.
Below is the code:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantName, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName;
        var resourceUrl = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
        var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientCred);
        var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        return token; 
    }

    [FunctionName("RestartWorkerJob")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        var tenantName = "";
        var clientId = "";
        var clientSecret = "";

        var token = GetAccessToken(tenantName, clientId, clientSecret).Result;

        string url = "https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription_id}/services/hostedservices/testworkerrole/deployments/{deployment_name}/roleinstances/WorkerRole1_IN_0";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength.ToString(), "0");
        try
        {
            var task = client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith((taskwithmsg) =>
            {
                var response = taskwithmsg.Result;

                var Text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    log.Trace(new TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Info, "Restart was successful"));
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Trace(new TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error, "Restart was unsuccessful"));
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Trace(new TraceEvent(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error, ex.Message));
        }}
```

using this approach gives me error 403-forbidden. 
The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

I can't understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Does this code work locally? Can you confirm the token you are getting is valid, and maybe try using it yourself in a curl or Postman request to validate the token is valid?

Comment: Token seems to be valid as it gives me 403 forbidden, when token is invalid it give 401 unauthorized. that's I have checked.

Answer (score 2):

The error 403 could be caused by permission issue or SPN expired.

When you register your web app with azure ad, for API permissions, select `Azure Service Management`. Select `Delegated permissions` and `user_impersonation`.

[image]

Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication) to use Resource Manager authentication API.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication) does authorization is necessary once I get access token as shown in my code?
When I am trying to use authorization endpoint in postman, it returns me html of azure login page. I am new to azure and not sure about the flow.

Comment: In your code, you add the bearer token with your Authorization header is all right to authorize. When in postman, add your token in `Authorization` and if the token is right, you will ok. As your description, it show you login page, it means you need to add your credential, so just add token in postman.

Comment: If it helps you, you could mark it as answer to close this issue.